# Pointcut expression not matching the Spring Data method despite specfying exact name in expression

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, aop, spring-aop

In my Spring Boot project, I have AddressRepository that brings all addresses from Database. I have an Aspect class and a pointcut expression that executes after the `findAll()` method called. When I execute my test case, the Advice is not being triggered and other methods like `findAll(Sort sort)`, `findAll(Pageable pageable)` work just fine. I am not sure if this is a bug with Spring Boot or my expression. I tried with Spring Boot 2.0.5 and 2.1.0, nothing seemed to solve my problem

**AddressLogging.java**

```java
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class AddressLogging {
    private Logger log=LoggerFactory.getLogger(AddressLogging.class);

    //@Pointcut("execution(* com.springtesting.repo.AddressRepository.*(..))")
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.springtesting.repo.AddressRepository.findAll())")
    public void getAddresses() {}

    @After("getAddresses()")
    public void afterAdvice() {
        log.error("Log Message: Inside afterAdvice() advice");
    }
}
```

**AopTest.java**

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AopTest {
    @Autowired
    private AddressRepository addressRepository;

    @Test
    public void getAddresses() {
        //addressRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0,20, Sort.by("id")));
        addressRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void findAddressById() {
        addressRepository.findById(1L);
    }
}
```

**AddressRepository**

```java
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address,Long> {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Spring AOP aspect should also be a `@Component` and be picked up by component scan. I have no idea why you added `@Configuration` to the aspect instead because there is no configuration here.

Maybe your test of a separate configuration class should bear the `@Configuration` annotation and you should also activate something like `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)` and `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "de.scrum_master" })`.

Here is a snippet from one of my Spring AOP playground projects (I hardly use it, I don't use Spring AOP or even Spring itself, usually I use the more powerful AspectJ:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "de.scrum_master" })
public class Application2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application2.class);
    B b = (B) appContext.getBean("b");
    System.out.println(b.getData("bbb"));
    A a = (A) appContext.getBean("b");
    System.out.println(a.getData("aaa"));
  }
}
```